# Ayuda sobre con la siguiente consulta de MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema para realizar una consulta en MYSQL ya que tengo poca experiencia. Necesito que me de una mano con lo siguiente:
.Tengo una tabla con dos campos
.Hay fechas repetidas
.No tiene que tomar la última fecha más actual de cada cliente.

```
Tabla Cliente 

|id_Cliente| Fecha |
|----------|-------|
|    1     |10/4/20|
|    2     |12/4/20|
|    2     |10/4/20|
|    3     |12/4/20|
|    3     |12/4/20|   
|    3     |28/5/20|
|    3     |30/7/20|
|    7     |06/4/22|
|    8     |08/4/21|
|    9     |22/5/20|
```

El problema es que cuando hago la consulta en las que los clientes tienen 3 fechas no me toma la que estan entre el medio de la max y min, y tambien si hay dos fechas repetidas de max me toma las dos como max y debería salir una de esas.

Comment: Incluye el código de tu consulta.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna Fecha?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuando haces que consulta?? que datos te vienen?? que datos queres que vengan??

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL 8.x puedes user la functión `ROW_NUMBER()` para identificar la fila correspondiente a la última fecha. Luego, aplicar el filtro es simple.

Por ejemplo:

```
select
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by id_cliente order by fecha desc) as rn  
  from cliente
) x
where rn = 1
```